# Error in Preferences

Tags: android

How to fetch data from android in EditText preferences & save it to another variable?

Comment: are you trying to extract text from an EditText or from the SharedPreferences?

Comment: hi Sheikh Aman  i am trying to extract text from SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("AnyFileName", MODE_PRIVATE);
String data = sharedPref.getString("myData","no data found");
```

I think this should help you

Comment: :-)  If it solved your problem, you may want to mark it as an accepted answer by checking the green tick.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Using Shared Preferences section here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). I *think* that is what you actually meant.